# Div push away from divs when I mouse over the div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am running Masonry and all my post container divs and I want the title and tags to appear when I hover over the post div. I am trying to display the title on top of the post and the tags to appear under the post and push the other posts around it when I hover over the post.

When I hover on a post the title display properly pushing the div above it away but the bottom div does not push away instead it appears under the post below it.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/solxs9/8vLKE/1/)

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="post">
     <div class="title">Post Title</div>
     <div class="image2"></div>
     <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image2"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
     <div class="title">Post Title</div>
     <div class="image1"></div>
     <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image2"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image2"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
    </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is that masonry is using absolute positioning, so divs below can't move that way. You can add z-index so Post details appears on the div below.

Comment: Exact duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178175/div-push-other-divs-on-hover

Answer (score 0):

As Jakub mentioned, the positioning is wrong. In your example i added

```
#content div{
        position: static !important;
    }
```

And it corrects the problem. Although this works. It still isn't functioning how you would want. I recommend building a new container div, setting your margins and padding's on the div "squares" throughout that container div, until its working as desired.