# Div push other divs on hover

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am running Masonry and all my posts and I want the title and tags to appear when I hover over the post. I am trying to display the title on top of the image and the tags to appear under the image and push the other posts around it when I hover over the post.

When I hover on a post the title display properly pushing the div above it away but the bottom div does not push away instead it appears under the post below it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/solxs9/8vLKE/1/)

```
#content {width: 210px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto;font-size: 10px;}
.post {width: 50px; padding: 2px 2px; float: left; z-index: 1;}
.post:hover .title {display: block;}
.post:hover .details{display: block;}
.title {display: none; z-index: 999;}
.image1 {width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid red;}
.image2 {width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid blue;}
.details {display: none; z-index: 999;}

<div id="content">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image2"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image2"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
   <div class="title">Post Title</div>
   <div class="image1"></div>
   <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
   <div class="post">
   <div class="title">Post Title</div>
   <div class="image2"></div>
   <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image2"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="title">Post Title</div>
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="details">Post Details</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div push away from divs when I mouse over the div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176613/div-push-away-from-divs-when-i-mouse-over-the-div)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need is to change order of those elements, in following fashion.

```
<div class="post">
 <div class="title">Post Title</div>
 <div class="details">Post Details</div>
 <div class="image2"></div>    
</div>
```

You are loosing the mosaic efect because of relative positioning and floating. When `:hover`your element is increased in proportions. You can try playing with positions. Adding `position:absolute` to `title` and `details` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: That does not help. I want the details to appear under the image not under the title.

Comment: [result](http://s28.postimg.org/z1y1motkt/screen.png) This is default result of your post. Details under image. Is this not what you want ?

Comment: That is what i want but i want to keep the mosaic layout.

Comment: And That would you want to achieve how ? Draw over ?